# powershell: save users passwords encrypted in file to compare

Tags: powershell

I want to accomplish following task:
I want to be able to run a powershell script, which allows a user to enter his username and a password. These two things have to be stored in a file. the password has to be encrypted.
two thoughts about it:

- **It could be for every user a single text file which contains the
  encrypted password.**
- It could be one large file containing every
  usernames and matching passwords.

I think the first way is the better one.

I have to be able to execute another script which can compare the encrypted password with an entered one.

(Goal: It will be part of some kind of self service password reset. So the stored passwords are the answers to  userdefined recovery questions which. )
Are there any examples in the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something along the means of

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$credential | Export-CliXml -Path "C:\Users\Archiv\Test.xml"
```

Overwriting the Old File every time.

And if you want to use the Credentials in PS

```
$credential = Import-CliXml -Path "C:\Users\Archiv\Test.xml"
Restart-Computer -ComputerName   default`
                 -Authentication default`
                 -Credential $credential
```